# StructureMap, Entity Framework, and IRepository/IUnitOfWork Configuration

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm using StructureMap with Entity Framework and IRepository/IUnitOfWork patterns on an ASP.NET MVC app.  The goal is to have all of the objects scoped to the current HTTP request, as follows:

```
For<ObjectContext>()
    .HttpContextScoped()
        .Use<MembershipEntities>()
            .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
                .Is("name=MembershipEntities")
        .Named(MembershipObjectContextInstanceKey);

For<IObjectContext>()
    .HttpContextScoped()
        .Use<ObjectContextAdapter>()
            .Ctor<ObjectContext>("objectContext")
                .Is(c => c.GetInstance<ObjectContext>(MembershipObjectContextInstanceKey))
        .Named(MembershipIObjectContextInstanceKey);

For<IUnitOfWork>()
    .HttpContextScoped()
        .Use<UnitOfWork>()
            .Ctor<IObjectContext>("objectContext")
                .Is(x => x.GetInstance<IObjectContext>(MembershipIObjectContextInstanceKey))
        .Named(MembershipUOWInstanceKey);

For(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .HttpContextScoped()
        .Use(typeof(Repository<>))
            .CtorDependency<IObjectContext>("objectContext")
                .IsNamedInstance(MembershipIObjectContextInstanceKey)
        .Named(MembershipIRepositoryInstanceKey);
```

However, when I run this code and get a named instance of a IRepository and a IUnitOfWork, their internal IObjectContexts are not the same instance, which is not my intent.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> StructureMap supports two forms of Dependency Injection:
>
> 1. **Constructor Injection** -- "Pushing" dependencies into a concrete class through constructor arguments.
> 2. Setter Injection -- "Pushing" dependencies into a concrete class through public properties.  The "Setter" nomenclature is taken from
>      Java where properties are getSomething() and setSomething(value).

I've had great results using a configuration similar to the following:

```
// In my projects, I have something like a DataContext (IDataContext's implementation) expose my ObjectContext...
// * You don't need to HttpContextScope everything, usually the ObjectContext is sufficient
For<ObjectContext>()
    .HttpContextScoped()
    .Use<MembershipEntities>()
    .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
    .Is("name=MembershipEntities")
    .Named(MembershipObjectContextInstanceKey);

// Usually, I don't abstract or wrap the ObjectContext, it is simply injected, under the hood
// ObjectContextAdapter receives an ObjectContext (HttpContextScoped)
For<IObjectContext>().Use<ObjectContextAdapter>();

// Ctor receives a IObjectContext
// * Again, if you have absolutely no use for IObjectContext, it shouldn't exist and UnitOfWork's ctor should receive the HttpContextScoped ObjectContext
For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<UnitOfWork>();

// Ctor receives a IObjectContext [...]
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
```

This is more or less how I do it, everytime.

Let me know if it works for you.
Sincerely,
Max